# tkinter display partially the output. Part of the content isn't visible

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem with the Windows Power Shell console, Anaconda console - in each of them, some part of the code isn't displayed when the window is generated. I don't know what's the reason. My system is win 10, Python 3, Anaconda 1.9.7. Codes are from a few tutorials. When code is slightly more complex it won't work. Example below.

the code:

```
from tkinter import *
  
root = Tk()  
root.geometry("400x300") 
v2 = DoubleVar()
  
def show2():
      
    sel = "Vertical Scale Value = " + str(v2.get()) 
    l2.config(text = sel, font =("Courier", 14))
  
s2 = Scale( root, variable = v2,
           from_ = 50, to = 1,
           orient = VERTICAL) 
  
l4 = Label(root, text = "Vertical Scaler")
  
b2 = Button(root, text ="Display Vertical",
            command = show2,
            bg = "purple", 
            fg = "white")
  
l2 = Label(root)
  
s2.pack(anchor = CENTER) 
l4.pack()
b2.pack()
l2.pack()
  
root.mainloop()
```

[expected and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhhgY.png)

When I pasted this code into each console, the output was such:

console output(Anaconda):

```
PS C:\Users\b2b> python
Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tkinter import *
>>>
>>> root = Tk()
>>> root.geometry("400x300")
''
>>> v2 = DoubleVar()
>>>
>>> def show2():
...
...     sel = "Vertical Scale Value = " + str(v2.get())
...     l2.config(text = sel, font =("Courier", 14))
...
... s2 = Scale( root, variable = v2,
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    s2 = Scale( root, variable = v2,
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>            from_ = 50, to = 1,
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from_ = 50, to = 1,
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>            orient = VERTICAL)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    orient = VERTICAL)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>> l4 = Label(root, text = "Vertical Scaler")
>>>
>>> b2 = Button(root, text ="Display Vertical",
...             command = show2,
...             bg = "purple",
...             fg = "white")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'show2' is not defined
>>>
>>> l2 = Label(root)
>>>
>>> s2.pack(anchor = CENTER)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 's2' is not defined
>>> l4.pack()
>>> b2.pack()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b2' is not defined
>>> l2.pack()
>>>
>>> root.mainloop()
```

[The Window created by Anaconda console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lazd.png)

Windows Power Shell (opened by Windows Terminal Preview) output:

```
PS C:\Users\b2b> python
Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tkinter import *
>>>
>>> root = Tk()
>>> root.geometry("400x300")
''
>>> v2 = DoubleVar()
>>>
>>> def show2():
...
...     sel = "Vertical Scale Value = " + str(v2.get())
...     l2.config(text = sel, font =("Courier", 14))
...
... s2 = Scale( root, variable = v2,
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    s2 = Scale( root, variable = v2,
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>            from_ = 50, to = 1,
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from_ = 50, to = 1,
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>            orient = VERTICAL)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    orient = VERTICAL)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>> l4 = Label(root, text = "Vertical Scaler")
>>>
>>> b2 = Button(root, text ="Display Vertical",
...             command = show2,
...             bg = "purple",
...             fg = "white")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'show2' is not defined
>>>
>>> l2 = Label(root)
>>>
>>> s2.pack(anchor = CENTER)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 's2' is not defined
>>> l4.pack()
>>> b2.pack()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b2' is not defined
>>> l2.pack()
>>>
>>> root.mainloop()
```

[window created by Windows Power Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xKR2.png)

Comment: Why are you creating a window in an interactive environment

Comment: The window created perfectly as expected when I run in IDLE. try running in anaconda as a script instead of pasting the code in a shell.

Comment: Also, due to invalid syntax, only a label is visible

Comment: You need to make the `()` close on the same line unlike the IDLE, where you can use `( `and close it next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend running it as a script instead of a terminal.

if you still wanna execute line by line and see the output, PLease follow the below method. I have brought functions to one line by adding ';' to avoid syntax errors and indent errors and it's working perfectly.

My Console Looks like,

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> root.geometry("300x300")
''
>>> v2 = DoubleVar()
>>> s2 = Scale( root, variable = v2, from_ = 50, to = 1, orient = VERTICAL)
>>> l4 = Label(root, text = "Vertical Scaler")
>>> s2.pack(anchor = CENTER);l4.pack()
>>> l2 = Label(root)
>>> l2.pack()
>>> def show2():sel = "Vertical Scale Value = " + str(v2.get());l2.config(text = sel, font =("Courier", 14));

>>> b2 = Button(root, text ="Display Vertical", command = show2, bg = "purple", fg = "white")
>>> b2.pack()
>>>
```

Output:

[image: Output Snip]

Answer (score 1):

When you get an error on some line/code block in interactive mode, that line (code) is not executed.
To use this code, you need to re-enter it without errors.

```py
>>> def foo:
    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    foo()
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
>>> def foo():
        print("OK")

    
>>> foo()
OK
>>>
```

Also works for tkinter:

```py
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> root.geometry("400x300zzz")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    root.geometry("400x300zzz")
  File "...\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1835, in wm_geometry
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "400x300zzz"
>>> root.geometry("400x300")
''
>>> label = Label(text="Text")
>>> label.pack()
>>>
```

The `l4` label is packed without errors, so you can see it.
The `l2` label is also packed in the root window, but there is no text in it.